# Query hbase with spark HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hbase

I'm trying to query a Hbase table with spark but i get this error :

> 14:08:35.134 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell - Failed to
>   detect a valid hadoop home directory java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset.

I have set the HADOOP_HOME in .bashrc and echo $HADOOP_HOME give me the path

my code :

```
    object HbaseQuery {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HBaseRead").setMaster("local[2]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    val tableName = "emp"

    System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.6")
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost")
    conf.set("hbase.master", "localhost:60000")

    conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, tableName)

    val hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[TableInputFormat], classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[Result])
    println("Number of Records found : " + hBaseRDD.count())
    hBaseRDD.foreach(println)

  }
}
```

i tried to create spark-env.sh too by adding 
export HADOOP_HOME="my path" 
but still the same problem 
Thank's in advance

Comment: Does your spark user have access to the hadoop directory?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, how do you check it ?

Comment: Check permission on the directory  using "ls -l " command. It will list the permission like "rwxrwxrwx" format. and also the user and group name

Comment: Thank's i checked and i have all the permissions